# When connecting Twitter and Facebook, can posts be filtered?

Tags: facebook, twitter, linkedin

I have both Facebook and Twitter accounts. I also use Linkedin.

If I want a tweet to appear in my LinkedIn profile, I add the hashtag `#in`.

Is there a way to do something similar with feeding Facebook from Twitter, so that not every tweet gets copied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an application like [Selective Tweets](https://www.facebook.com/selectivetwitter) or [TweetPo.st](http://tweetpo.st/) so your tweets ending with hashtag #fb will be automatically imported to Facebook, while all others will be ignored.

Comment: just what I was trying to find :) -thanks